# Ayuda - QEMU: Windows XP virtual en Windows 10 (64 bits)

Tags: windows10, virtualización

He encontrado toda la información que he podido pero hasta ahora no puedo configurar bien la máquina virtual de Windows XP del programa QEMU en Windows 10.

Estos son los comandos que he utilizado, la instalación parece correcta pero
1) no funciona bien el ratón
2) no puedo conectar a Internet (ni activar Windows XP) desde la máquina virtual
3) no puedo intercambiar archivos ni el portapapeles ni arrastrar/copiar/pegar entre anfitrión e invitado

Agradecería mucho que alguien pudiera ayudarme.

Comando para crear una unidad virtual:

```
qemu-img create -f qcow "Windows XP Home Edition.img" 40G
```

Comando para instalar Windows XP:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -cdrom WindowsXP.Home.SP3.iso -m 512 -boot d "Windows XP Home Edition.img" -name "Windows XP Home Edition"
```

Comando para abrir/ejecutar la máquina virtual (igual que el de instalar Windows XP pero sin la opción -cdrom):

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 512 -boot d "Windows XP Home Edition.img" -name "Windows XP Home Edition"
```

Answer (score 1):

Este es mi inicio con mouse habilitado y teclado, pc I7 y 4M en ram

```
qemu-system-x86_64.exe -enable-kvm -machine type=pc-q35-3.1,accel=tcg -cpu Nehalem-IBRS -smp 2 -m 4096 -vga std -device ich9-usb-uhci6 -device usb-tablet -device usb-kbd -hda Disco.img
```